# How could I use egg yolk from boiled eggs?

Tags: composting, waste-minimisation, biodegradable-waste, food-waste

Both my wife and I avoid eating yolk (as much as possible). I know I can find some uses for raw yolk but I am not sure if the yolk from boiled eggs can be put to good use, other than forms that involve eating them (directly or indirectly).

While at it I'd like advice on putting to good use the raw yolks too. We eat about 30 eggs in a week. One of the challenges would also be storage before processing them in any way. Thoughts and ideas?

We have container based plants (avocadoes, tomatoes, peppers, flowers) and so gardening uses are welcome too.

Comment: Hello and welcome.  The obvious answer is that you could eat them.  Perhaps you could expand your question to cover the reasons this solution doesn't currently seem feasible to you.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone - As I indicated in my question, solutions that involving eating in some form or the other is not what I'm looking for. As for why not, the yolk is full of cholesterol, which we could avoid.

Comment: Dietary cholesterol is an essential part of human nutrition.  An individual falling within the normal range of human health shouldn't be concerned about consuming it.  There are many citations available for this.  I might put them in an answer.  This is why I asked you to add reasons.  Perhaps there is a medical condition involved which really does preclude consumption.  Or perhaps there's just a misunderstanding of the health consequences of consuming egg yolks.

Comment: :) I think that should be a discussion with one's dietician/physician or a post in medical stackexchange. From a sustainability standpoint how else could I use the yolk?

Comment: Animal feed. Whilst you may not be keen to eat egg yolk, other birds and mammals would be delighted.

Comment: @ChristopherGilmour I think this could be an answer, if you added a bit more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are already putting some or all of the egg shell in with your plants.

I looked around and using egg yolk as a fertilizer has several issues. If you have an outdoor compost pile you could add them to that, but mixing large amounts of animal protein in a compost pile can be problematic, so I would use caution depending on how much plant organics you are adding to the compost pile.

> Eco-Cycle recommends that whole eggs not be composted, although eggshells can be composted (eggshells are high in calcium and good for the soil). There are three reasons for this recommendation.
>
> Whole eggs tend to attract unwanted attention from animals such as mice, skunks, buzzards, and bears. Biting insects may also lay eggs in compost that contains whole eggs, leading to more flies and more bites.
>
> The bacteria that do most of the work in a compost pile are aerobic bacteria, which require oxygen to digest waste. These bacteria oxidize carbon compounds and generate heat as a by-product of their growth and reproduction. This heat accelerates the activity of other bacteria, speeding the breakdown of materials in a compost pile. In contrast, the bacteria that thrive on meat scraps and other high protein sources, such as eggs, are anaerobic. Anaerobic bacteria grow quickly without fresh air. They break down proteins to generate energy, but do not produce much heat.
>
> The by-products from the breakdown of eggs can make a compost pile stink.
> [Source](https://articles.extension.org/pages/65612/can-i-compost-hard-boiled-eggs)

A comment mentions using egg yolks to feed carnivores and/or omnivores.  You don't mention any pets in your question, if you have pets you should probably talk to your vet about it.

I found several posts online about feeding eggs to birds.  If you are in the habit of feeding the wild birds, adding egg yolk to the wild bird feed seems like a viable option.

> Eggs are a powerful food that feeds the brains of these sharp creatures. It takes a certain amount of intelligence to survive in the wild, so a meal from an egg is a good choice. Egg yolks contain choline which is a serious brain food because it makes rapid thinking far easier by speeding up the relay signals in the brain. The choline found in eggs also aid liver function and transferring and distributing nutrients throughout the body where it is needed. [Source](https://www.thesprucepets.com/are-eggs-good-for-my-bird-390604)

Comment: thank you for the elaborate response with sources. We don't have pets but we do have cats (likely neighbors') that visit and also birds. We already use a bird feeder and put nuts in them. I tried breaking the boiled yolk and adding them to the feeder. So far it looks like it works.
Needless to say, the cats love them.